# git config environment variables

Tags: git, environment-variables

I hope you can answer me today!

Docs from `git help commit` says:

> ```
> COMMIT INFORMATION
>   Author and committer information is taken from the following
>   environment variables, if set:
>
>       GIT_AUTHOR_NAME
>       GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL
>       GIT_AUTHOR_DATE
>       GIT_COMMITTER_NAME
>       GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL
>       GIT_COMMITTER_DATE
> ```

I set `GIT_AUTHOR_NAME`, `GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL`, `GIT_COMMITTER_NAME` and `GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL` variables by doing these commands:

```
# export GIT_AUTHOR_NAME=".."
# export GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL=".."
# export GIT_COMMITER_NAME=".."
# export GIT_COMMITER_EMAIL=".."
```

I checked their content with `echo`

But `git commit` command still says me:

```
# git commit
Author identity unknown

*** Please tell me who you are.

Run

  git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
  git config --global user.name "Your Name"

to set your account's default identity.
Omit --global to set the identity only in this repository.

fatal: unable to auto-detect email address (got 'root@fedora.(none)')
```

*I need to do it as root for some reason*

Yes, I know that I can simply do that `git config ..` command, but it's curious to me why I can't tell git this info with these environment variables

Comment: Can you show us the exact commands you ran to set those environment variables and do the commit (as a code block by editing your question)?

Comment: In short, don't do anything as root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was my typos in settings `GIT_COMMITTER_xxx` variables (you can see them at question body). Setting actual variables works as intended.

Answer (score 1):

> I need to do it as root for some reason

if you have:

- set those variables as your regular user, and then executed a `sudo git commit`
- or the reverse: set those variables using sudo, and then executed a regular `git commit`

Then `git` command would not see the `GIT_xxx` variables, and fall back to the configuration (which was not set)

Comment: Actually I set these variables as regular user previously, but I then I realized that I can't do `git commit` command without root (it's special partition)

Comment: @snakeCascade Exactly what I say in my answer: setting variables as regular user, but using `git` as `root` means the `git` command won't see those variables. At all.

Comment: But I set these variables as root, and ran command `git commit` also as root

Comment: @snakeCascade What command did you use to set the variable as root?

Comment: I wrote about it in question body

Comment: @snakeCascade Any chance you can retry all that as regular user, without any sudo or su root involved?

Comment: Yes, I've just did it now, after solving the problem, and it works